# Cassandra aggregate to Map

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax

I am new to cassandra, I've mainly been using Hive the past several months. Recently I started a project where I need to do some of the things I did in hive with cassandra instead.

Essentially, I am trying to find a way to do an aggregate of multiple rows into a single map on query.

In hive, I simply do a group by, with a "map" aggregate. Does a way exist in cassandra to do something similar?

Here is an example of a working hive query that does the task I am looking to do:

```
select 
      map(
        "quantity", count(caseid)
        , "title" ,casesubcat
        , "id" , casesubcatid
        , "category", named_struct("id",casecatid,'title',casecat) 
      ) as casedata
from caselist
group by named_struct("id",casecatid,'title',casecat) , casesubcat, casesubcatid
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping query results to Map (or some other type/structure/class of your choice) is responsibility of client application and usually is a trivial task (but you didn't specify in what context this map is going to be used).

Actual question here is about `GROUP BY` in Cassandra. This is not supported out of the box. You can check Cassandra's [standard aggregate functions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryStdAggregate.html) or  try creating [user defined function](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html), but **Cassandra Way** is knowing your query in advance, designing your schema accordingly, doing heavy lifting in write phase and simplistic querying afterwards. Thus, grouping/aggregation can often be achieved by using dedicated [counter tables](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html).

Another option is to do data processing in additional layer (Apache Spark, for example). Have you considered using Hive on top of Cassandra?